# Should extension shims be avoided in Composer?

Tags: composer-php

Let's say I have some code in a package that requires `ext-oauth` to handle OAuth signature generation.

```
{  
    "name":"vendor/my-package",
    "type":"library",
    "require":{  
        "ext-oauth":"*"
    }
}
```

When I try to install this package on a system that doesn't have the extension, Composer raises an error, as expected.

```
$ composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested PHP extension ext-oauth * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's oauth extension.
```

Clearly the `ext-oauth` package is missing on this system, checking via `composer show --platform` confirms this.

Assume the system *can't* be updated to include the extension, virtualization (via Docker or Vagrant) also isn't an option. Would hacking around it by using a `package` that `provide`s the `ext-oauth` extension or `require`'ng a package from packagist be a reasonable solution?

This synthetic test *appears* to work.

```
{  
    "name":"vendor/my-package",
    "type":"library",
    "require":{  
        "vendor/ext-oauth":"1.0",
        "ext-oauth":"*"
    },
    "repositories":[  
        {  
            "type":"package",
            "package":{  
                "name":"vendor/ext-oauth",
                "version":"1.0",
                "dist":{  
                    "url":"https://example.com/ext-oauth.zip",
                    "type":"zip"
                },
                "provide":{  
                    "ext-oauth":"1.0"
                },
                "autoload":[
                    "files":[
                        "src/oauth.php",
                        "src/oauthexception.php" 
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Composer then downloads the provided shim and installs it, marking the `ext-oauth` dependency as met.

```
$ composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing vendor/ext-oauth (1.0): Downloading (100%)         
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

This feels wrong, but appears to accomplish satisfying the dependency in a maintainable way. Is there a good reason - other than code smell - to avoid providing this sort of shim when PHP extensions can't be installed?